# Can't find FileManager Swift class in Foundation, where is it?

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

The Apple documentation talks about the Swift class `FileManager`, but Xcode is not recognizing it as part of Foundation, I get the error below. Where is this class then?

It says `Use of unresolved identifier 'FileManager'`.
I thought this was a new API that would replace NSFileManager.

[image]

Btw, the app documentation that talks about it is here:
[FileManager class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager)

Comment: Please add the code that produced the error and add the error message completely.

Answer (score 7):

You need to "import Foundation" before using the FileManager class.

```
import Foundation

let fileManager = FileManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's **NSFileManager()**

```
let fileManager =  NSFileManager.defaultManager()
```

Comment: It's NSFileManager in Swift 2 and FileManager in Swift 3.